# How to run a function when route changes?

Tags: flutter

I have made a circular menu widget that opens to show the menu options, when the user clicks on it, it goes to another screen, but if the user press the back button on android it goes back to the menu screen with the circular menu still open(also the distance of the submenus to the main circle increase):
[image: I cropped the video just to show the button]

(I cropped the video just to show the button, the downward pointing triangle is part of the next screen)

I want to close the circular menu whenever the user selects any option in the submenu, so basically I want to run the close() function before changing routes, or any other way of making the button close

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frontend/utils/degrees_to_radians.dart';
import 'package:frontend/utils/indexed_iterables.dart';

class CircularMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget menuIcon;
  final List<Widget>? children;
  CircularMenu({Key? key, this.children, required this.menuIcon})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CircularMenuState createState() => _CircularMenuState();
}

class _CircularMenuState extends State<CircularMenu>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _isOpen = false;
  bool _isAnimating = false;

  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late AnimationController _subMenuPositionController;
  late Animation<double> _sizeAnimation;
  late Animation<double> _subMenuPositionAnimation;

  void open() {
    setState(() {
      _isOpen = true;
      _animationController.forward();
      _subMenuPositionController.forward();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), vsync: this);

    _subMenuPositionController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);

    _sizeAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0.4)
              .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut)),
          weight: 50),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.4, end: 0.9)
              .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut)),
          weight: 50),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.9, end: 0.3)
              .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut)),
          weight: 50),
    ]).animate(_animationController);
      /* ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _subMenuPositionController.forward();
        }
      });
 */
    _subMenuPositionAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 75)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.bounceIn))
        .animate(_subMenuPositionController);

    super.initState();
  }


  void close() {
    setState(() {
      _isOpen = false;
      _animationController.reverse();
      _subMenuPositionController.reverse();
    });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        builder: (context, _) {
          return Container(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                if(widget.children != null)
                ..._renderSubMenu(
                    widget.children!, _subMenuPositionAnimation.value),

                //Center Button
                FractionallySizedBox(
                  widthFactor: _sizeAnimation.value,
                  heightFactor: _sizeAnimation.value,
                  child: Container(
                    child: RawMaterialButton(
                      fillColor: Colors.blue,
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_isAnimating) return;

                        if (_isOpen) {
                          close();
                        } else {
                          open();
                        }
                      },
                      child: Center(child: _isOpen ? Icon(Icons.close) : widget.menuIcon),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  List<Widget> _renderSubMenu(List<Widget> children, double distance) {
    List<Widget> _subMenu = [];
    double _angleRatio = 360 / children.length;

    children.forEachIndexed((child, index) {
      _subMenu.add(
        Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset.fromDirection(
                convertDegreesToRadians(index * _angleRatio), distance),
            child: GestureDetector(
                            child: child)),
      );
    });

    return _subMenu;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just pass close callback to submenu elements and call it after navigator push, without awaiting push completion. though you should change children list to builder one, so you can adjust callback to specific button.

also you should mutate state first and after check if widget is mounted before setting its state, smth like this:

```
  void close() {
      _isOpen = false;
      _animationController.reverse();
      _subMenuPositionController.reverse();
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
  }
```

Comment: i completed a working example, you could see it here
https://dartpad.dev/?id=be84056a3664cae12a03204fb6b0d339&null_safety=true